# Changes to the program. IDA disassembler

Tags: x86, ida, disassembly

There is such part of a code.

```
 /* bla bla bla */
.text:0040C777                 align 4
.text:0040C778
.text:0040C778 loc_40C778:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_40C424+289j
.text:0040C778                 mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 493E0h
.text:0040C780                 mov     eax, [ebx+88h]
.text:0040C786                 mov     [esp], eax
.text:0040C789                 call    ds:_ZN6QTimer5startEi
.text:0040C78F                 lea     esp, [ebp-0Ch]
.text:0040C792                 pop     ebx
.text:0040C793                 pop     esi
.text:0040C794                 pop     edi
.text:0040C795                 leave
.text:0040C796                 retn
 /* bla bla bla */
```

I want to change the value "**493E0h**" to another. How to do it in IDA? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Patching binaries with IDA is fun ^__^

Here are some links to tutorials that should help you out:

- http://marcoramilli.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-patch-binary-with-ida-pro.html
- http://www.woodmann.com/TiGa/idaseries.html

Comment: I can not change value in hex-view?

Answer (score 1):

What I do it highlight the instruction you want to change, swap to Hex view highlight that plus more, do a binary search for that blob, if there is only one result, open your original executable in a hex editor, search for the same blob (there should only be one occurrence) and make your change there.